# Where can I ask a question seeking service?

Tags: discussion

I am [looking for a service](https://superuser.com/questions/771769/where-do-i-turn-to-to-upgrade-non-upgradable-hardware) to upgrade 'non-upgradable' hardware. Where on Stack Exchange network can I ask a question like that and how do I phrase it so that it would be legal?

Comment: The website does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that kind of question has no real definite answer, and as such is more a shopping question. It is like this across the entire network, not just at Super User.

Your best bet to find a good answer would be to drop by our chat room, [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access). There are usually plenty of people hanging out who love to recommend hardware, products and services. It is more than welcome in chat, just not as a question on the site.